# Select Current Database Name OR Not Current Database Name in SQL Server for a Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have two databases in SQL Server. Let's say they are DB1 and DB2.
When the system starts, the current database is always DB1. BTW, I have to use DB2 for another table.

For the reason, I want to give a table name as a variable like @tablename and want to select a database name for the @tablename. Would it be possible to pull the database name associated with @tablename?

Also, I want to save the database name to a variable like @databasename to print it out.

When I tried to find a database name from the code below, I could get the database name of the table, ExampleTable, among DB1 and DB2.

```
EXEC sys.sp_msforeachdb
'SELECT ''?'' DatabaseName, name FROM [?].sys.Tables WHERE Name = ''ExampleTable'''
```

However, I can't go forward to process how to make a code using a variable @table instead of a fixed table name, ExampleTable.

I will use list of tables to input @tablename into the query one by one from the list.

```
DECLARE @table sysname = 'TableNames';
DECLARE @database_name sysname = 'dbo';
DECLARE @DatabaseName VARCHAR(50)

-- tbl_01 in dbo.DB1
-- tbl_02 in dbo.DB2
-- tbl_03 in dbo.DB1
-- tbl_04 in dbo.DB2


/*
   I need the code block
   (1) To input a table using @table
   (2) To save the database name to a variable like @database_name 

EXEC sys.sp_msforeachdb
'SELECT ''?'' DatabaseName, name FROM [?].sys.Tables WHERE Name ='+@table

*/
```

Please help me to create a script for my work.

Comment: _When the system starts, the current database is always DB1._ That's not actually a thing. Probably what's happening here is that your SQL/Windows Login has DB1 set as its default database.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thank you for the comment. The connect to database option in MS SQL Server Management Studio is default and I'm using the server as a user, not admin. While I can't see the default setting, the current database is always DB1 when I log in the DB server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code contains a set of tools you can use to do what you want to do. I expect your requirements may change a bit as you do this, so that's why I'm giving you the tools first.

These tools are written as simple checks - easy to understand and relatively quick. They currently just do a `SELECT 'Yes'` if the database exists/etc - but of course you can change that as needed.

```
DECLARE @DBName_1 nvarchar(100) = N'DB1';
DECLARE @DBName_2 nvarchar(100) = N'DB2';
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(100) = N'MyTable';
DECLARE @TableNameToCheck nvarchar(200);

-- Is the current database 'DB1'?
IF DB_Name() = @DBName_1 SELECT 'Yes' ELSE SELECT 'No';

-- Check if the database 'DB2' exists
IF DB_ID(@DBName_2) IS NOT NULL SELECT 'Yes' ELSE SELECT 'No';

-- Check if table is in first database
SET @TableNameToCheck = QUOTENAME(@DBName_1) + N'.[dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);
IF OBJECT_ID(@TableNameToCheck, 'U') IS NOT NULL SELECT 'Yes' ELSE SELECT 'No';

-- Check if table is in second database (note it uses @DBName_2)
SET @TableNameToCheck = QUOTENAME(@DBName_2) + N'.[dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);
IF OBJECT_ID(@TableNameToCheck, 'U') IS NOT NULL SELECT 'Yes' ELSE SELECT 'No';
```

Note that you do not actually *need* the variable @TableNameToCheck - you can just construct it within the `OBJECT_ID()` function e.g., `OBJECT_ID(@DBName_2 + N'.dbo.' + @TableName , 'U')`. However, it can be useful to set it first to check/ensure it's correct, and it has infinitesimal impact on performance.

For your actual task (recording whether the table exists in DB1 or DB2) you can do the following

```
DECLARE @DBName_1 nvarchar(100) = N'DB1';
DECLARE @DBName_2 nvarchar(100) = N'DB2';
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(100) = N'MyTable';
DECLARE @DatabaseWithTable nvarchar(100);

IF OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(@DBName_1) + N'.[dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@TableName), 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
    SET @DatabaseWithTable = @DBName_1;
    END
ELSE IF OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(@DBName_2) + N'.[dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@TableName), 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
    SET @DatabaseWithTable = @DBName_2;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    SET @DatabaseWithTable = N'Not Found';
    END;

SELECT @DatabaseWithTable;
```

Edit: Added QUOTENAME() as per suggestion/comment from @HABO

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: Thanks @HABO and good point. I have updated the answer with QUOTENAME for all names generated via concatenation.

Comment: @seanb - Thank you so much for taking your time and helping me to solve the problem! I will definitely start from your suggestion and will post the result.

Comment: @HABO - Thank you very much for adding the important point for the problem solving!

Comment: @seanb - I appreciate your taking the time and sharing the code with me. It works really well. Thanks again! I can select a specific database for any table now!